# Change css with Selectors via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to change the background color of `input:cheked` with JS, but I don't know how

```
  input:checked{
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
```

I tried changing the bg color of the object with the class "input", but I need to change `input:checked` there is already an answer on Stack Overflow, but unfortunately all the solutions don't fit in my code because I'm working with many loops and `chrome.runtime.onMessage`

```
var v1 = document.createElement("input")
v1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create the element rather than just change an existing element. If you want to change existing boxes' color... something like
`document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach(e => e.style.backgroundColor = "red")`